# React Hooks and Conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The "[Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)" mention:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Does that also mean we should avoid code like this?

```
const useMyCoolHook = ({configKey, anotherProp}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Do something with configKey here
  }, [configKey])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do something with configKey and anotherProp here
  }, [configKey, anotherProp])
}

const Component = ({configKey, anotherProp}) => {
  if(configKey === undefined) { return null; }

  useMyCoolHook({configKey, anotherProp})

  return (
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  )
}
```

If so, is there a way to avoid having to include the condition inside each of the `useEffect` hooks?

Comment: No, what you've done is fine and correct, in fact we can see more or less the canonical example of a hook https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ looks like what you do. What is meant is that you shouldn't have like if(x) useCoolHook(), or for(x in w) useCoolHook(), and you shouldn't have defined useMyCoolHook inside of Component (which you didn't).

Comment: @Countingstuff You can not conditionally call a hook, if you do `if(condition) return;useSomeHook()` then when `condition` is true the component will early return and not call the hook for that render. The linter will tell you `Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?` So OP code is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have so far looks like a normal [curstom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). However; the way you call it is wrong, the linter should give you the following warning:

> React Hook "useMyCoolHook" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

The following will have the linter stop giving you warnings but you have to repeatedly check for the value of configKey:

```
const useMyCoolHook = ({ configKey, anotherProp }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (configKey !== undefined) {
      // Do something with configKey here
    }
  }, [configKey]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (configKey !== undefined) {
      // Do something with configKey and anotherProp here
    }
  }, [configKey, anotherProp]);
};

const Component = ({ configKey, anotherProp }) => {
  useMyCoolHook({ configKey, anotherProp });
  if (configKey === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return <h1>Hello world</h1>;
};
```

A wrapper component is another option to check `configKey` before attempting to render `Component`

```
const ComponentWrapper = ({configKey, anotherProp}) => {
  if (configKey) {
    return <Component configKey={configKey} anotherProp={anotherProp}/>
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought also. I was hoping to avoid checking `configKey` in each hook because those could be imported or out of my control. I could create a wrapper component to check `configKey` before trying to render `Component` to avoid the check in each hook, what do you think?

Comment: @Sandro Good idea for the wrapper, if you return:  `return Component({configKey, anotherProp});` instead it'll save on the nesting.